# reltable is not working with dita open tool kit 3.0

Tags: dita

I have created the file below. But it is giving me an error in dita open tool kit version 3.0.

```
{?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?}
{!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd"}
{map id="ducks"}
 {title}Ducks{/title}

  {reltable}
  {relheader}
   {relcolspec type="concept"/}
   {relcolspec type="task"/}
   {relcolspec type="reference"/}
  {/relheader}
  {relrow}
   {relcell}{topicref href="c.dita"/}{/relcell}
   {relcell}{topicref href="t.dita"/}{/relcell}
   {relcell}{topicref href="r.dita"/}{/relcell}
  {/relrow}
 {/reltable}
{/map}
```

The files `c.dita` (concept), `t.dita` (task) or `r.dita` (reference) are available.

Regards

Deepak Bhatia

Comment: Please also specify the error being generated.

Comment: [fop] SEVERE: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:flow" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:10711)
      [fop] [ERROR] Anttask - Error rendering fo file: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\temp20180108104353403\topic.fo <org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:flow" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:10711)
      [fop] net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:flow" is miss

Comment: [fop] net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:flow" is missing child elements. Required content model: marker* (%block;)+ (See position 1:10711)
      [fop]  at org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.FOPTaskStarter.renderInputHandler(Fop.java:650)
      [fop]  at org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.FOPTaskStarter.render(Fop.java:669)
      [fop]  at org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.FOPTaskStarter.run(Fop.java:530)
      [fop]  at org.apache.fop.tools.anttasks.Fop.execute(Fop.java:367)

Answer (score 3):

Is this the full map? If so, then the problem is you are missing the structure that generates the output. Add topicref elements to build the content sand it should work.

Comment: Thanks yes when I add the topicref then it works. Then what is the use of reltable, I am new to dita.

Comment: Well, in <reltable> you refer to other topics and therefore you have to have content also. For example if you have one topic at the content, DITA OT (PDF) will write to the PDF, that "Related xxxx" and there is the topic which is mentioned in <reltable> for example with "(topic title) on page X". In plain words: it's like "read more from here" instruction to the reader.